# How to make a DropDown in a menu? Koala-Framework

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, koala-framework

I'm developing a website with Koala-Framework and i need to add a custom drop-down menu next to menu or exactly in a menu.

Is this possible and what's the best approach?

It should open when hovering over the menu-item and the menu-item shouldn't be clickable... (but it's no problem if it's not possible to disable...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible :)
(I was told so personally ^^)

There are (at least) two ways to implement this behavior:

- Create a box and set the position in Root/Master.tpl
- Implement it in your Menu-Component

The How-Tos are a little complicated and can be found on http://www.koala-framework.org/documentation soon...